# Is onchnge() function works in jquerymobile 1.4.2

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am using jquerymobile 1.4.2.This the code which i am using in my page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
<head>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
 </script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js">  </script>
  </head>
   <body>


 <script>
  function myFunction()
     {
    document.getElementById("myText").disabled=true;
    }
    </script>

<p>Click the button to disable the text field.</p>

 <select onchange="myFunction()"><option>1</option><option>2</option></select>

 First Name: <input type="text" id="myText">

 </body>
 </html>
```

The above program works fine But if i change that to this code

```
<script>
  function myFunction()
     {
    document.getElementById("myText").disabled=false;
    }
    </script>
<p>Click the button to disable the text field.</p>

 <select onchange="myFunction()"><option>1</option><option>2</option></select>

 First Name: <input type="text" id="myText" disabled="disabled">
```

Then its not working please help me how to make text field enable using onchange() function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQM enhances the input and creates a Textinput widget which has its own enable/disable methods (http://api.jquerymobile.com/textinput/#method-disable)

In your example, to enable the input:

```
function myFunction() {
    $("#myText").textinput("enable");
}
```

Also, you should use unobtrusive javascript and the jQM page functions. e.g. remove the onclick from the markup:

```
<select id="theSelect" >
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select>First Name:
<input type="text" id="myText" disabled="disabled" />
```

Add the handler in the pagecreate jQM event:

```
function myFunction(selVal) {
    if (selVal == '2'){
        $("#myText").textinput("enable");
    } else {
        $("#myText").textinput("disable");
    }
}

$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page1", function () {
    $("#theSelect").on("change", function(){
        var v = $(this).val();
        myFunction(v);
    });
});
```

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/78ts2/)**